# Angular 4 Service method returns always undefined instead Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, socket.io, rxjs

I wrote an angular service which connects with socket.io to my backend. I get the server data in the `_getStripes()` method correctly and transform them with `from()` into an Observable and set the class variable `_LEDs` with the recent created observable.

The public method `getStripes()` is called and subscribed in another component and returns everytime `undefined`.

**led.service.ts:**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import {LED} from './led';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {from} from 'rxjs/observable/from';

@Injectable()
export class LedService {
  private _io;
  private _LEDs: Observable<LED>;

  constructor() {
    this._io = io('http://localhost:80');
    // Subscribe getStripes Event
    this._io.on('getStripes', this._getStripes);

    // Initial Request Stripes from Server
    this._io.emit('getStripes');
  }

  /**
   * Server Response
   * @param {LED[]} data
   * @private
   */
  private _getStripes(data: LED[]) {
    console.log('Got Stripes: ', data); // works
    this._LEDs = from(data);
  }

  /**
   * Get the current connected LEDStripes
   * @returns {Observable<LED>}
   */
  public getStripes(): Observable<LED> {
    // request latest Stripes
    this._io.emit('getStripes');
    return this._LEDs; // always undefined
  }

  public setStripeColor(name: string, color: string) {
    this._io.emit('setStripeColor', name, color);
  }

}
```

Comment: Could this be a race condition? I would guess that the the `return` is happening before the `emit` is handled. Just as a test, what happens if you sleep between the `emit` and `return` in `getStripes`to give everything else a chance to 'settle'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the subscription from the emit.

Subscription sets up the pipeline to receive incoming data, but emit sends data. It looks like it's request/response style, since the event and emit params are the same string, but in any case there is a time delay between the two, so the pipeline needs to be established prior.

Try using a **Subject** for `this._LEDS`.

**In the service**

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
...
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class LedService {
  private _io;
  private _LEDs = new Subject<LED>();
  public LEDs = this._LEDs.asObservable();  // Subscribe to this

  constructor() {
    ...
    // Subscribe getStripes Event
    this._io.on('getStripes', this._getStripes.bind(this) );
    ...
  }

  /**
   * Server Response
   * @param {LED[]} data
   * @private
   */
  private _getStripes(data: LED[]) {
    data.forEach(led => this._LEDs.next(led));
    // OR send the whole array as a single emit if it suits your application better
    //    this._LEDs.next(data);
    // in which case the declaration above would be
    //    private _LEDs = new Subject<LED[]>();
  }

  /**
   * Get the current connected LEDStripes
   * @returns void
   */
  public getStripes(): void {
    // request latest Stripes
    this._io.emit('getStripes');
  }
```

**In the component**

```js
ngOnInit() {
  // subscribe to the LEDs
  this.sub = this.ledService.LEDS.subscribe(leds => {
    // do something with data
  }) 
  // or use the subscription directly in the template
  // with <div> {{ (ledService.LEDS | async) }} </div>
}

getFresh() {
  this.ledService.getStripes();
}
```

Comment: Got this error in the forEach Loop: `Cannot read property 'next' of undefined ` I already checked if I missed something.

Comment: The `.next` is on `this._LEDs`, so either there's a capitalization difference between this line and the declaration line, or perhaps you've not initialized it on the declaration line (`:` instead of `=`)?

Comment: NB I'm making a typo in the above comment (fixed it)

Comment: Indeed, strange. Might take a moment.

Comment: I'd say it's a `this` problem. Could you please `console.log('this', this)` on the line above and see what properties it has? I suspect it will show properties of the event handler in `socket.io-client` and not those of your service.

Comment: You are right! this=socket. But why changed 'this' the context??

Comment: It's the ES6 fat-arrow syntax which takes it's this context from where it's being run (paraphrasing). I'll work out an alternative way to call.

Comment: The usual way to fix it is to use `function` syntax like `data.forEach(function(led) { this._LEDs.next(led) });`. Could you please try this variation.

Comment: Hmm no, doesn't work because the this context is in the whole `_getStripes()` method on the socket. I tried creating a private `_this` class variable and set `_this=this` inside the constructor. But inside the `_getStripes()` method it is not possible to reach the class variable `_this`

Comment: Okay. Found a solution, but im not happy with it. I just subscribed inside the LedService constructor and made a temp `__this` var: https://pastebin.com/f0pYYyLS

Comment: Well done. I'll keep looking for an alternative but working is better than not!

Comment: I think `this._getStripes.bind(this)` will give the correct context, but I can't easily test it - can you confirm please?